# connect session save redundant?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

How does connect's session work? I'm following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-complete-mvc-web-site-with-expressjs/). I've noticed that even though i've commented out the `session.save()` call everything still works, that property still gets persisted to the session. Does Express automatically call `session.save()` every time a response is served up? If that's the case, what is the purpose of the save method?

```
var BaseController = require('./Base'),
    View = require('../views/Base');

module.exports = BaseController.extend({
    name: 'Admin',
    username: 'dadams',
    password: 'dadams',
    run: function(req, res, next) {
        if(this.authorize(req)) {
            req.session.fastdelivery = true;
          //  req.session.save(function(err) {
                var v = new View(res, 'admin');
                v.render({
                    title: 'Administration',
                    content: 'Welcome to the control panel'
                });
          //  });
        } else {
            var v = new View(res, 'admin-login');
            v.render({
                title: 'Please login'
            });
        }
    },
    authorize: function(req) {
        return (
            req.session &&
                req.session.fastdelivery &&
                req.session.fastdelivery === true
            ) || (
            req.body &&
                req.body.username === this.username &&
                req.body.password === this.password
            );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect’s session handling is automatic. Looking at [the code](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html), `save` gets called automatically on `res.end` (when your response is sent), so there’s no need to call it separately.

Consider it an implementation detail that’s exposed to you. I can’t think of many reasons why you would use it. Maybe if you are saving to Redis or a database and you want the session to be committed early for some reason, before calling end?

Comment: where is the .end() method defined? i'm new to javascript on the backend. i can't seem to find anything

Comment: In the middleware code at the bottom of that page, look for `// proxy end() to commit the session`. It replaces the `res.end()` method with a wrapper that saves your session and then calls the original `res.end()`.